# What range must a spell cast "on" a Shield Guardian have?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, targeting

The "Spell Storing" ability of the Shield Guardian says:

> To do so, the wearer must **cast the spell on the guardian**.  The spell has no effect but is stored within the guardian.

This seems to indicate you cannot cast, for instance, *Fire Shield* on the Guardian, because that has a range of Self.

This seems different than what is intended, as the wording for a ring of spell storing is:

> This ring stores spells **cast into it**, holding them until the attuned
>   wearer uses them....Any creature can cast a spell of 1st through 5th
>   level **into the ring by touching the ring as the spell is cast**.  The spell has no effect, other than to be stored in the
>   ring.

The use of the word "into," which does not seem to indicate any range, versus the use of the word "on," which seems to mean the guardian is a target of the spell.

Which is the correct interpretation, grammatically, versus what is the RAI?

Answer (score 11):

### Your reading is correct: the Shield Guardian must be the target.

The phrasing "cast spell on [x]" is used consistently throughout the PHB, and always refers to [x] being the target of that spell. Here are some examples:

Nystul's Magic Aura:

> **If you cast this spell on the same creature or object every day** for 30 days, placing the same effect on it each time, the illusion lasts until it is dispelled.

"Breaking up your move" (PHB 190):

> For example, if you have a speed of 30 and a flying speed of 60 **because a wizard cast the fly spell on you,** you could fly 20 feet, then walk 10 feet, and then leap into the air to fly 30 feet more.

Animate Dead:

> To maintain control of the creature for another 24 hours, **you must cast this spell on the creature** again before the current 24-hour period ends.

Therefore, the Shield Guardian can only store spells that can target it, which precludes spells with a range of "self".

It's worth noting that the Shield Guardian is a creature, and is thus a legal target for spells that target a creature, whereas the the Ring of Spell Storing is not a creature. This difference might account for the difference in wording between the two.

Comment: Does this mean that the Shield Guardian _cannot_ store spells that are cast at a point in space, such as most AoE spells?  Casting a fireball _at_ the Guardian is not casting a fireball 'on' it because it is not the target of the spell?

Answer (score 3):

The Ring simply functions differently and has no bearing on how the Shield Guardian functions. The similar names are irrelevant and don't override the actual descriptions of the different functions.

A Shield Guardian must be targetable by the normal spell targeting rules for its **Spell Storing** ability to proc. Spells with range of Self can't target the Shield Guardian and therefore can't be stored in a Shield Guardian.