# How to know if a spell can be stored in a Shield Guardian?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The [Shield Guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shield-guardian) has the following feature:

> ***Spell Storing.*** A spellcaster who wears the shield guardian's amulet can cause the guardian to store one spell of 4th level or lower. To do so, **the wearer must cast the spell on the guardian.** The spell has no effect but is stored within the guardian. When commanded to do so by the wearer or when a situation arises that was predefined by the spellcaster, the guardian casts the stored spell with any parameters set by the original caster, requiring no components. When the spell is cast or a new spell is stored, any previously stored spell is lost.

I'm unsure what the bolded phrase *requires/means*. Does the spell just needs to target the Guardian for it to be stored? What counts as casting a spell *on* a Shield Guardian? What are the criteria for whether or not a spell can be stored in a Shield Guardian?

Comment: The question that comes to my mind when reading yours: does casting a spell "on" the Shield Guardian mean following the normal rules for [Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#Targets)?

Comment: Possibly related: [Can you store a casting of counterspell in a shield guardian?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/157344/can-you-store-a-casting-of-counterspell-in-a-shield-guardian)

Comment: Are there any specific spells that you're wanting to cast on the Shield Guardian? I believe I could write a more appropriate answer if I knew what sort of spell you were after. From how the question is worded currently, I would just say something along the lines of, "If it targets it, you can cast it", but that's a very vague and easy to exploit answer.

Comment: I think it means the caster is required to mount the shield guardian and cast the spell while astride it. KIDDING! Isn't language fun?

Comment: @Rykara Funny, but re: language, that would be more properly stated as "the wearer must cast the spell _while_ on the guardian."

Answer (score 2):

I think @mattdm correctly pointed out in a comment on the question that it follows the normal rules for [Targets](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) when it says: cast the spell **on** something.

A good explanation and examples are given in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/104972/35026) to a similar question about the the range to cast a spell **on** the [Shield Guardian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/shield-guardian).

---

Additional information:

In this aspect the Shield Guardian's spell storing works different than the [Ring of Spell Storing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) or the 2019 UA Artificer's 18th-level class feature [Spell-Storing Item](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer2-2019.pdf#page=6) where the caster stores the spell simply by touching the object.

An other difference is that the spell storing ability of the Shield Guardian uses the spell save DC of the spellcaster.

Comment: Great find with that other Q/A! Thank you. I'm feeling it may be a duplicate of mine though

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.